# How to make switch case ignore punctuation marks in a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<textarea>` where i type something and i receive below, a specific answer depending on what I typed. I found a problem when i write with punctuation marks, it doesn't give me the expected answer. How do i make switch cases ignore punctuation marks?

Here's my code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<textarea id="box" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<p id="output"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var text = document.getElementById("output");
var str = document.getElementById("box").value.toLowerCase();
switch(str){
case "hi": text.innerHTML = "Hi there!";break;
case "hello": text.innerHTML = "Hello,hello!";break;
case "good morning":  text.innerHTML = "Good morning, pal!";break;
case "good evening":  text.innerHTML = "Good evening, sir!";break;
default:
text.innerHTML = "I don't know what to say. Try to say 'hello' or 'hi'.";break;

}
}
</script>
```

Comment: switch/case makes exact comparison, you cannot alter its behavior. though you can adjust your input string

Comment: Just remove all punctuation marks from the string before passing it into switch. Lowercasing the string might be a good idea too.

Comment: i solve it. Thank you for the suggestion @Андрей Беньковский .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to remove all punctuation marks from the string before passing it into the switch:

[run code](https://jsbin.com/vatokuboho/2/edit?js,console)

```
var input = "H.E,L:;!?L()[o]{}";
// You can add more punctuation into the regex if you need 
var str = input.toLowerCase().replace(/[.,:;!?(){}\[\]]+/g, '');
var result;
switch(str){    
    case "hi": result = "Hi there!";break;
    case "hello": result = "Hello,hello!";break;
    case "good morning": result = "Good morning, pal!";break;
    case "good evening": result = "Good evening, sir!";break;
    default:
    result = "I don't know what to say. Try to say 'hello' or 'hi'.";break;
}
```

output:

```
Hello,hello!
```

BTW: in your specific situation I'd use an object instead of a switch-case:

[run code](https://jsbin.com/fodabaqiva/edit?js,console)

```
var responses = { 
    hi: "Hi there!",
    hello: "Hello,hello!",
    "good morning": "Good morning, pal!",
    "good evening": "Good evening, sir!"
};
var default_response = "I don't know what to say. Try to say 'hello' or 'hi'.";

var input = "H.E,L:;!?L()[o]{}";
var key = input.toLowerCase().replace(/[.,:;!?(){}\[\]]+/g, '');
var result = key in responses ? responses[key] : default_response;
```